# Is there a organ or type of cell that makes Nagalase?

Tags: immune-system, organs, organic-chemistry, autoimmune

[Schindler disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schindler_disease) / Kanzaki disease is being described as alpha-N-acetylgalactosaminidase deficiency. So then, which organ or cell(s) produce this alpha-N-acetylgalactosaminidase (Nagalase) ?